# Type argument MousEvent is not within bounds of type-variable T

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'm trying to double click at an item on a ListView and then something should happen. While i found a few solutions here and also found a post with this exact error, I'm not really able to solve it myself.

My example code:

```
public class MainTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     new test();
        
    }
}


public class Test extends AnchorPane implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{   
    private ListView<String> list = new ListView<String>();
    
    public Test() {
    super();
    
    list.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
          
        }

    
        });  
    }
}
```

I need the `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` for a button.

Full error:

> ```
> Type argument MousEvent is not within bounds of type-variable T where T is a type-variable: T extends Event declared in interface EventHandler
>
> incompatible types: <anonymous EventHandler<java.awt.event.MouseEvent>> cannot be converted to EventHandler<? super javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>
> ```

Comment: You are using `AWT` for `JavaFX`

Comment: Import `javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent` instead of `java.awt.event.MouseEvent`.

Comment: i cannot believe that this was the whole problem.. thank you very much!